# function that is accessing an array declared outside - php

Tags: php, arrays, scope

I'm surprised I'm not able to access an array in a function without passing it to the function

```
$arr = [-4,3,-9,0,4,1]; 
function print_array()
{
    print_r($arr);
}
print_array();
```

when I run, I'm getting **Notice: Undefined variable arr**

I though since the array and the function are in the same file, I would be able to access it? Can I not access the array without passing it to the function? I have a bunch of arrays outside, that I need to print in the function. But I don't want to pass each one of them.

Comment: pass $arr like an argument of the function.. `function print_array($arr){print_r($arr);}`

Comment: Why should you be surprised? It's called [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).... scope isn't file-based, it's function-based

Comment: @MarkBaker but the array is declared outside the function right. I'm confused.

Comment: It's declared outside the function, so it doesn't exist inside the function unless you explicitly make it available to that function (typically by passing it into the function as an argument)

Comment: if you want to use $arr inside the function  write "global $arr;" before the print_r. but that's not a good way to do things.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks everyone for your help. I came from C background, in C you can directly access variables declared outside , in a function without passing them as arguments